# Completion/Threading order assistance

Tags: swift, multithreading, closures, completionhandler

I'm messing up the order of my completion handlers and likely my threading as well. I used print statements and timers to check my work and here is what I found:

1. Time Lapsed is 0.00076 seconds which is obviously not the intended behaviour.
2. Step 4 is shown right away which is again not the intended behaviour.
3. Step 1 is shown
4. Step 2 is show with a time of 2.92 seconds which is fine.

Only thing to fix is to have Step 4 at the very end as it would mean that Step 1 and 2 are completed.

This function is in class A:

```
static func loadDataAndSignIn(completion: @escaping () -> () ) {

    let start = Date()

        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { (result, error) in
            if result != nil {

                print("Step 1 -> Signed In. UserId is: \(result?.user.uid)")

                Variables.getDataFromFirestore {

                    let end = Date()

                    print("Step 2 - > Data Fetched")
                    print("Data Fetched in \(end.timeIntervalSince(start)) seconds")
                }
            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? print("Sign in Error"))
            }
        }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         completion()
        print("Step 4 -> Signed In and Data Loaded")
    }
 }
```

This function is also in class A:

```
static func getDataFromFirestore(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("Offences").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                Variables.offencesArray.removeAll()

                for offence in snapshot!.documents {

                    let offenceName = offence.get("name") as! String
                    let offencePoints = offence.get("points") as! Int
                    let offenceCost = offence.get("cost") as! Int
                    let offenceSection = offence.get("section") as! String
                    let offenceCategory = offence.get("category") as! String

                    let offenceObject = Offence(section: offenceSection, name: offenceName, cost: offenceCost, points: offencePoints, category: offenceCategory)

                    Variables.offencesArray.append(offenceObject)
                }
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion?()
            } 
        }   
}
```

This is in viewDidLoad of class B:

```
 let start = Date()

    Variables.loadDataAndSignIn {

        self.removeLoadingScreen()

        let end = Date()

        print("Time lapsed: \(end.timeIntervalSince(start))")
    }
```

A need a hand to get my threading/completion blocks back in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your call to `completion` inside the completion handler of `getDataFromFirestore`, which is inside the completion handler of `signInAnonymously`:

```
static func loadDataAndSignIn(completion: @escaping () -> () ) {
    Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { (result, error) in
        if result != nil {
            print("Step 1 -> Signed In. UserId is: \(result?.user.uid)")

            Variables.getDataFromFirestore {
                let end = Date()

                print("Step 2 - > Data Fetched")
                print("Data Fetched in \(end.timeIntervalSince(start)) seconds")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion()
                    print("Step 4 -> Signed In and Data Loaded")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Sign in Error")
        }
    }
}
```

Note: you may want to also call completion if `result` from the call to `signInAnonymously` is nil, like:

```
[...]
        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Sign in Error")

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion()
            }
        }
```